# How to add a generated column with an expression subtracting days?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, computed-column, interval

I have this table in PostgreSQL 13:

```
CREATE TABLE public."domain" (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    domain_name varchar NOT NULL,
    -- more columns
    expire_date timestamp NULL,
    days_before_trigger int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 14
);
```

Now I want to add a generated column `notify_trigger_date`, derived from `expire_date` minus `days_before_trigger`, to record my website url ssl certificate expiry date. How to auto-generate that column?
It can look like this:

```
notify_trigger_date = expire_date - 7 day
```

I am trying to implement it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "domain" ADD COLUMN notify_trigger_date timestamp 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((expire_date::timestamp - '1 day')) STORED;
```

I do not know how to replace the `1 day` with the number of days from `days_before_trigger`? This command runs with error:

> ```
> SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1 day"
> ```

What should I do to make it work? I have read the PostgreSQL documentation but found no clear solution for this.

Comment: Please provide your exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement including all relevant columns) and tell us where the variable (dynamic?) number of days comes from. Is it a column in the same table?

Comment: According the answer of Lennart, problem solved smoothly.@ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: The column name is "expire_date" and you only speak of a "days". Is there a time component? If so, I'd assume that the time zone is also relevant. So I'd expect `date` or `timestamptz`, not `timestamp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include INTERVAL in your calculation:

```
ALTER TABLE D ADD COLUMN notify_trigger_date timestamp
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expire_date - INTERVAL '1 day') STORED;
```

If the amount of days is stored in a column, you can create an interval of that and then subtract it. Here is one example:

```
ALTER TABLE D ADD COLUMN notify_trigger_date date
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        expire_date - make_interval(days => days_before_trigger)
    ) STORED;
```

Comment: how to replace 1 for dynamic? `ALTER TABLE "domain" ADD COLUMN notify_trigger_date timestamp 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((expire_date - interval (days_before_trigger ' day'))) STORED;`

Answer (score 7):

Typically, the best solution is to ***not*** store the functionally dependent value `notify_trigger_date` in the table at all. Just bloats the table. For `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, use the (very cheap!) expression instead:

```
expire_date - make_interval(days => days_before_trigger)
```

Or the equivalent (and equally cheap):

```
expire_date - interval '1 day' * days_before_trigger
```

Works with any version of Postgres, while [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) was added with Postgres 10.

If the column `expire_date` is type **`date`** instead of `timestamp`, use the simpler (and even cheaper) expression:

```
expire_date - days_before_trigger
```

You can just subtract `integer` from `date`. Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945281/939860)

If you need an index on the (virtual) column `notify_trigger_date`, I would suggest an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) like (assuming the `date` variant):

```
CREATE INDEX ON public."domain" ((expire_date - days_before_trigger)); -- parentheses required
```

And repeat the same expression in queries:

```
SELECT * FROM "domain"
WHERE (expire_date - days_before_trigger) <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Related:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860)